# Save model with updated weights in pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, save, pytorch

I have a model that I want to train for 5 epochs. Then, I would like to see where the model was wrong and increase the training set accordingly. How can I save the following model with the learnt weight?

```py
trainer_ = Trainer(network = network,
                       optimizer = optim.Adam(network.parameters(), lr=0.001),
                       loss_function = loss_function,
                       train_loader = train_loader,
                       valid_every = 100,
                       print_every = 50,
                       save_every = 15000,
                       save_path = ".",
                       cudaok = is_cuda_available)

trainer_.run(4,is_cuda_available)
```

I have tried this:

```py
path = os.path.join(project_path, 'model.pth')
torch.save(network.cpu().state_dict(), path) # saving model
```

But I don't really think that the object `network` contains weights.

I am very confused here. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: why does `torch.save` not meet your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`network.state_dict()` is a `dictionary`; try this to see your weights:

```
for param in network.state_dict():
    print(param, "\n", network.state_dict()[param])
```

Comment: awesome, so when I have saved this model as above I can load it. How do I tell python to run next epochs with the saved model?

Comment: it is explained in detail [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html). You should save your model and your optimizer parameters; later load both of them and feed them to the `Trainer`.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the model correctly.
Now to load the weights into the model, you create a new model with the arguments:

```
network = Network(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then load the saved weights into it:

```
network.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))
```

Comment: what do args and kwargs represent here?

Comment: Whatever arguments or keyword arguments your model requires, for example the number of layers, whether to use batchnorm or not, the size of the layers, etc.